# Find row number of previous instance of string in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula

Hello I have a column of string IDs and for any given row I want to extract 1. what string ID it has and 2. the next and 3. previous rows that the string occurs on.  My example spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N266gqKq8b06fRgDjnKT2W1PL_27Vw_C0OIMsDie5nQ/edit?usp=sharing).

I can do the first two but I can't find a way to use MATCH to find the previous value

I can find the next value with:

```
=MATCH(E4,indirect("A"&E3+1):A20,0)+E3
```

for example
if input = 7

ID = asd

Next = 8

Last = 7

or
input = 9

id = zxc

Next = 18

last = 5

Answer (score 0):

Odd requirement so UNTESTED but may be worth a try (`1` would be an error):

```
=match(999,ArrayFormula(1*substitute(indirect("A1:A"&E5-1),"zxc",row())))
```